# Remote desktop connection WITHOUT login screen on remote computer

Tags: c#, desktop, rdp

I have written some C# code that allows me to establish a remote desktop connection using `AxMSTSCLib`.

So far so good. Works like a charm.

However, what I actually need is to simply mirror the remote desktop.
with a standard RDP connection the remote computer transmits the desktop content to the client and shows the login screen locally, thereby rendering the remote computer inoperable locally.
I need a simple desktop mirroring solution.
RDP has all the components I need, so I don't want to utilize any 3rd party software unless I absolutely have to.

My question is: is there a setting in the RDP that causes the remote computer to show its desktop instead of the login screen?

I am happy to use a different approach to `AxMSTSCLib` if I have to.